# Pandas Dataframe extraction from columns with mixed entries

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, regex-group

at the moment i am using a excel sheet as an example for evaluation.
Its an copy of an import where the Programm tends to fill column with mixed entries.

In Excel its look like this:
[Excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HqRg.jpg)

My Code looks like this in VS Code:

```
   # 03.01.2024
   # Regex - Reguläre Ausdrücke zum Filtern, hier mit dem Frame aus der Auswertung

   import pandas as pd  
   import numpy as np
   from datetime import datetime

   from pandas import * 

   # Einlesen der Excel
   excel_file = 'F:\\Google Drive\\Matthias\\Arbeit\\ISQM\\08 - Tool Menü - Skripte DD                                                  19.12.2023\\Testskripte\\value_cnts_2.xlsx'  

  xlsx = ExcelFile(excel_file)                
  excel_Tabelle = xlsx.sheet_names[0]         
  df  = xlsx.parse(excel_Tabelle)  

  # df['Vorgänger'] = df['Vorgänger'].fillna(0)
  #df = df['Nachfolger'].str.replace('----', '')

  df['Verknüpfung1'] = df['Nachfolger'].str.extract('(?P<EE>EE)')
  #df['Verknüpfung3'] = df['Nachfolger'].str.extract('[EA+,AA,EA-]')
  df['Verknüpfung2'] = df['Nachfolger'].str.extract('(?P<EE>AA)')

  df['Verknüpfung1'] = df['Verknüpfung1'].fillna(0)
  df['Verknüpfung2'] = df['Verknüpfung2'].fillna(0)

  df`
`
```

I write the excel sheet into a pandas dataframe.
As you can see i am trying the regex expressions in the extract function.

With the regex101 editor i found some regex, the named capturing group, which give me this output:

```
Nachfolger  Verknüpfung1    Verknüpfung2
0   54;20   0   0
1   ----    0   0
2   ----    0   0
3   ----    0   0
4   ----    0   0
5   ----    0   0
6   ----    0   0
7   ----    0   0
8   ----    0   0
9   ----    0   0
10  ----    0   0
11  ----    0   0
12  ----    0   0
13  ----    0   0
14  ----    0   0
15  ----    0   0
16  21;4;49;50;51   0   0
17  52  0   0
18  ----    0   0
19  52;128AA;207;22;223 0   AA
20  ----    0   0
21  52;24   0   0
22  28  0   0
23  ----    0   0
24  52;227;27   0   0
25  30  0   0
26  227 0   0
27  ----    0   0
28  52;31   0   0
29  ----    0   0
30  138EE;34    EE  0
31  ----    0   0
32  139EE;36    EE  0
33  ----    0   0
34  140EE;38    EE  0
35  ----    0   0
36  141EE;40    EE  0
37  ----    0   0
```

I want to filter the columns which contains characters. I want to count them.

My Question now is there way where you can use regular expressions only in one column.
I tried another expression ([EA+,AA,EA-]) where i just get an Error.

Thank you!

Comment: What should be the result?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you expect is not clear. However, you can try:

```
df['Verknüpfung3'] = df['Nachfolger'].str.extract(r'(EA[+-]|AA)')

# OR

df['Verknüpfung'] = df['Nachfolger'].str.extract(r'(EE|EA[+-]|AA)')
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/XpetvS/1)

Comment: Hello! Got to admit i am a first timer here, i also dont get along with the formatting of this board right now.  My goal was to reduce the amount of columns in that frame while filtering the entries. with the regex. Anyway i try your solution now.

Comment: thanks for the help, the latter syntax gave the desired output.